# Is there a way to disable text preprocessing entirely with Marqo?

Tags: vector-search, marqo

I'm using Marqo Cloud and I don't want to use sentence or passage splits - i just want the whole text chunk to be in the embedding.

I couldn't see how to do it from the source code / docs but maybe i missed something else?